# Как поставить иконку на .exe файлы

Tags: exe

Как поставить иконку на .exe файлы ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bat - текстовый файл с расширением .bat, соответственно, в себе ресурсов не несет. Можно только в ОС сменить значок для файлов .bat, как и для любых других расширений.
Exe - если программу разрабатываешь сам, то смотря на чем, где-то в настройках проекта должно быть "выбрать/сменить иконку". Если имеется уже готовый исполняемый файл, можно его отредактировать *редактором ресурсов* (Restorator, PE Explorer, Resource Tuner, Resource Builder).

Comment: тогда меняю вопрос ...
как поставить иконку на exe файл ???

Comment: Exe - если программу пишешь сам, то смотря на чем пишешь, где-то в настройках проекта должно быть "выбрать/сменить иконку". Если имеется уже готовый исполняемый файл, нужно его отредактировать редактором ресурсов (Restorator, PE Explorer, Resource Tuner, Resource Builder).

Comment: если имеется ввиду все ехе на ПК то это настройки ОС